# Graphic count based on the Month using Lavachart on laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, charts, laravel-5

Hello i get stuck on this proble, hope you guys can give me some advice to solve this matter. So, i want to show graph that count basen on month, how many keluhan (complain) on that month. so the table will be like january has 3 complain, febuary has 5 complain, etc (example)

```
public function lihatkeluhan(){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan_list=DB::table('keluhans')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,tanggal,produk,username,area,masalah,status'))->get();

    $count = count($keluhan_list); //this still not count based on month
    $population = Lava::DataTable();
    $population->addDateColumn('Year')
               ->addNumberColumn('Keluhan')
               ->addRow(['?',$count]);

    Lava::LineChart('Population', $population, [
        'title' => 'Tahun : 2017',
        ]);

    return view('layanankonsumen.daftarkeluhan',compact('halaman','keluhan_list','lava'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try query like this.
it will gives you groupby result with count of that particular month,
no need for  $count = count($keluhan_list); because you will get count in result.

```
$keluhan_list=DB::table('keluhans')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,tanggal,produk,username,area,masalah,status,count(*) as count'))
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
          return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
     });
```

Comment: the code is error but thank for reply, can you fix it ?

Comment: Can you tell me the error please, so that i can fix that.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ';' i think the format code is wrong

Comment: ohh Yes got it, ->select(DB::raw('id,tanggal,produk,username,area,masalah,status,count(*) as count')

Comment: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given << error like this

Comment: Call to a member function groupBy() on array... btw what is $date ? is it variable ? we never declare it befor i think

Comment: it's calling groupby on object , and yes we don't need to declare $date. Is it worked?

Comment: not yet its still erorr buddy T_T error is Call to a member function groupBy() on array

Comment: it's working on my Query :/  Users::select(DB::raw('*,count(*) as count'))->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
          return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
     });

Comment: has you tried it on laravel too, its not work on mine haha T_T bad luck of mine

Comment: wait i have checked. you have used  DB::table('keluhans') and i used Model for same. that's why you are getting the error. if you have defined model for 'keluhans', please try using that model.

Comment: yup work, i got the result but how to implement into my chart ??

Comment: i use dd() to check and the result is Collection {#299 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "04" => Collection {#293 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}

i only have 3 data but it show 4 ?